# Apple Wallet / Passbook iOS 9 Automatic Updates disabled by default + Webservice Bug

Tags: web-services, ios9, passbook, applepay

When a QR-Code is scanned to get a new Pass, it's settings for "Automatic Updates" and "Show on Lockscreen" are disabled by default. In iOS Versions prior to 9.0 both where enabled. If the same Pass gets installed via the url inside the QR-Code both settings are set to on.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Scan QR-Code to download/install new pass
2. Pass will not register and is showing "Automatic Updates" as disabled
3. Open the URL within the same QR-Code with Safari and download the same Pass, all works fine

Moreover, when a Pass gets downloaded, Apple is calling the wrong Webservice URL. Instead of calling POST on the Registration REST Service, they are calling DELETE.

Tested with iOS9.0 and 9.1 (13B5110e) iPhone6

Does anyone have a workaround?

See also:

https://openradar.appspot.com/22816943

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/24585#24585

Comment: It's a known issue - please raise a bug at bugreport.apple.com - your independent report will help raise the priority of getting this fixed.

Comment: Thank you, for your reply. I already raised a bug https://openradar.appspot.com/22816943 and there is another one raised by another developer having the same issues... http://openradar.appspot.com/22835812

Comment: I have submitted the bug report to Apple and added my radar https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4566027815878656

Comment: My bug report 22816943 was closed as duplicate of 22300988 by Apple

Comment: I just installed the latest beta of iOS 9.1 beta 3 13B5130b (released 09/30/15), nothing has changed. "Automatic Updates" still disabled, Webservice is still not called correctly.

Comment: I installed  iOS 9.1 beta 4 (13B136), nothing has changed, still 'automatic updates' disabled by default and wrong Webservice calls from Apple.
Does anyone have more info on this?

Comment: As of iOS 9.2, the bug seems to be resolved for me. Could somebody else confirm?

Comment: Fixed in 9.2 (13С75)